# Medir tiempo ejecución algoritmo en Swift (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift2

Necesito medir el tiempo en el que se ejecuta un algoritmo en iOS. Por ejemplo: quiero comparar la velocidad en que se obtiene el Factorial de un número hecho por recursividad y hecho sin este.

Este es mi programa:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var numberInput: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func factorial(sender: AnyObject) {
        let numberInt = Int(numberInput.text!)
        if numberInt != nil!{
            let number = numberInt!
            let fact = factorial2(number)
            resultLabel.text = "El factorial es: \(fact)"
        } else{
            resultLabel.text = "Por favor, introduce un número"
        }
    }

    func factorial2(number: Int) -> (Int) {
        if (number <= 1) {
            return 1
        }
        return number * factorial2(number - 1)
    }
}
```

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer una marca de tiempo:

```
var inicio = NSDate()
```

Al finalizar la ejecución realizas nuevamente una marca de tiempo y mediante el metodo `timeIntervalSinceDate` de `NSDate` evaluas la diferencia.

```
var inicio = NSDate()
// codigo
var fin = NSDate()
fin.timeIntervalSinceDate(inicio);
```

Esto retornara la diferencia en segundos.

Comment: @Juansanchez, Similar a mi respuesta en Android, En iOS si requieres millisegundos [NSDate timeIntervalSinceDate:foo] * 1000 ya que NSTimeInterval siempre se obtienen segundos.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Elenasys !!